# Dual space of a finite dimensional is finite dimensional

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a normed space with dual $V^*$. Then $E$ is finite dimensional if and only if $V^*$ is finite dimensional, and in fact $\dim{V} =\dim{V^*}$.

I set up the proof as follows:  Let $\dim{(V)}=n.$  Then there exists a basis, $B=\{v_1, ...,v_n\}$.  Now assume $V^*$ is not finite dimensional.  Then there exists a basis $B^*=\{f_1,f_2,...,f_n, f_{n+1},...\}$ for $V^*$.  Let $f_i(v_j)=\delta_{ij}$, where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker Delta, and let $v=\sum_{j=1}^n{a_jv_j}$.  Then for $i=1..n,$
$$f_i(v)=f_i\left(\sum_{j=1}^n{a_jv_j}\right)=\sum_{j=1}^n{f_i(a_jv_j)}=\sum_{j=1}^n{a_jf_i(v_j)}=\sum_{j=1}^n{a_j\delta_{ij}}=a_i  $$
Now, take $i=n+1.$
$$f_{n+1}(v)=f_{n+1}\left(\sum_{j=1}^n{a_jv_j}\right)=\sum_{j=1}^n{f_{n+1}(a_jv_j)}=\sum_{j=1}^n{a_jf_{n+1}(v_j)}=\sum_{j=1}^n{a_j\delta_{(n+1)j}}=0  $$

This means that our basis for $V^*$, 
$$B^*=\{f_1, ..., f_n, f_{n+1},...\}=\{f_1,...,f_n, 0,0,...\}=\{f_1, ...,f_n\}$$
Therefore, since $B^*$ is a basis for $V^*$, $V^*$ is finite dimensional, and even better, $ \dim{(V^*)}=n$

Does this proof work for the finite dimensionality of $V^*$?

my proof is correct?

Comment: In your definition of $f_i$ for $i\ge n+1$, you automatically **defined** it to be zero. But in general it might not be true. Instead, you should try to show that all other $v\in V^*$ can be written as $b_1 f_1 + b_2 f_2 + \cdots b_n f_n$. (You are not far away from this)

Comment: Note this theorem has nothing to see with *normed* spaces. It is true for finite dimensional vector spaces over *any* field.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. When you say "... assume $V^*$ is not finite dimensional. Then there exists a basis $B^*=\{f_1,\dots \}$" you are assuming not only that $V^* $ is infinite dimensional, but rather that its dimension is countable. But of course the dimension need not be countable. Instead of assuming $V^*$ is not finite dimensional, simply construct a basis of $V^*$ from a given finite basis of $V$, having the exact same number of elements as the given basis of $V$ (this is called the dual basis). If $V$ is infinite dimensional, then take an infinite linearly independent set, and construct from it an infinite linearly independent set of linear functionals. That will suffice, and avoids needlessly counting transfinite dimensions.

Comment: my new idea with your help is : Suppose that $V$ is finite dimensional. Let $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ be a basis for $V$.....  but i cant solve the problem.